# Which value for a duplicate key is ignored in a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

If a hash has more than one occurrences of identical keys pointing to different values, then how does Ruby determine which value is assigned to that key?

In other words,

```
hash = {keyone: 'value1', keytwo: 'value2', keyone: 'value3'}
```

results in

```
warning: duplicated key at line 1 ignored: :keyone
```

but how do I know which value is assigned to `:keyone`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last one overwrites the previous values. In this case, `"value3"` becomes the value for `:keyone`. This works just as the same with `merge`. When you merge two hashes that have the same keys, the value in the latter hash (not the receiver but the argument) overwrites the other value.

Answer (score 2):

Line numbers on duplicate key warnings can be misleading.  As the other answers here confirm, every value of a duplicated key is ignored except for the **last** value defined for that key.

Using the example in the question across multiple lines:

```
1 hash1 = {key1: 'value1',
2 key2: 'value2', 
3 key1: 'value3'}
4 puts hash1.to_s

keydup.rb:1: warning: duplicated key at line 3 ignored: :key1
{:key1=>"value3", :key2=>"value2"}
```

The message says "line 3 ignored" but, in fact it was the value of the key defined at **line 1** that is ignored, and the value at line 3 is used, because that is the last value passed into that key.

Comment: I agree. The message is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

IRB is your friend. Try the following in the command line:

```
irb
hash = {keyone: 'value1', keytwo: 'value2', keyone: 'value3'}
hash[:keyone]
```

What did you get? Should be "value3".

Best way to check these things is simply to try it out. It's one of the great things about Ruby.

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out because of the annoying line numbers on the duplicate key warnings.  But yes, it's always the last value to be defined, regardless of the line number given in the warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is spelled out clearly in section 11.5.5.2 *Hash constructor* of the ISO Ruby Language Specification:

> ## 11.5.5.2 Hash constructor
>
> ### Semantics
>
> [...]
>
> b) 2) For each *association A<sub>i</sub>*, **in the order it appears in the program text**, take the following steps:
>
> i) Evaluate the *operator-expression* of the *association-key* of *A<sub>i</sub>*. Let *K<sub>i</sub>* be the resulting value.
>
> ii) Evaluate the *operator-expression* of the *association-value*. Let *V<sub>i</sub>* be the resulting value.
>
> iii) Store a pair of *K<sub>i</sub>* and *V<sub>i</sub>* in *H* by invoking the method `[]=` on *H* with *K<sub>i</sub>* and *V<sub>i</sub>* as the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for this clear reference to the documentation.